# Regex expression for extracting data using java

Tags: java, regex, text, special-characters

```
A lightweight window manager able to attach multiple windows to one frame.$^&/&^$ഒരു ഫ്രയിമില്‍ ഒന്നില്‍കൂടുതല്‍ ജാലകങ്ങള്‍ ചേര്‍ക്കാന്‍ കഴിവുള്ള കനംകുറഞ്ഞ ജാലകപാലകന്‍Name.

This section requires special permissions, probably for system-wide changes; therefore, it is required that you provide the root password to be able to change the module 's properties. If you cannot provide the password, the changes of the module cannot be saved.$^&/&^$Argument is application name.

A program error occurred: the internal program 'kdepasswd ' could not be found. You will not be able to change your password.$^&/&^$പ്രോഗ്രാമിനകത്തൊരു തെറ്റു് സംഭവിച്ചു: ' kdepasswd ' എന്ന ആന്തരിക പ്രോഗ്രാം കണ്ടുപിടിയ്ക്കാന്‍ സാധിച്ചില്ല. നിങ്ങളുടെ അടയാളവാക്കു് മാറ്റാന്‍ നിങ്ങള്‍ക്കു് സാധിയ്ക്കില്ല.

To be able to search a document, a search index needs to exist. The status column of the list below shows whether an index for a document exists.$^&/&^$ഒരു പ്രമാണം തിരയണമെങ്കില്‍ ഒരു തിരച്ചില്‍ ഇന്‍ഡെക്സ് ഉണ്ടായിരിക്കണം. താഴെയുള്ള പട്ടികയിലെ സ്ഥിതി കോളം പ്രമാണത്തിനു ഇന്‍ഡെക്സ് ഉണ്ടോ എന്നു കാണിക്കും.

Icons This module allows you to choose the icons for your desktop. To choose an icon theme, click on its name and apply your choice by pressing the " Apply " button below. If you do not want to apply your choice you can press the " Reset " button to discard your changes. By pressing the " Install New Theme " button you can install your new icon theme by writing its location in the box or browsing to the location. Press the " OK " button to finish the installation. The " Remove Theme " button will only be activated if you select a theme that you installed using this module. You are not able to remove globally installed themes here. You can also specify effects that should be applied to the icons.$^&/&^$NAME OF TRANSLATORS.
```

I need to extract only Malayalam data. That starts from `$^&/&^` to the end of the Malayalam characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
      //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

       //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
       int lineNumber = 1;
       while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
                                 String line = scnr.nextLine();
                                 System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
                                 lineNumber++;                                                                
                                 String[] parts = line.split("\\$");
                                 for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
                                 {
                                     System.out.println(parts[i]+"dell"+i);
                                     if(i==2)
                                     {
                                           bw.write(parts[i]); 
                                           bw.newLine();
                                     }
                                  }



    }                            


 }                               

 bw.close();
```